# Closing Realm and async requests

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

How properly close realm with async request, for example

```
RealmResults<RealmUser> realmResults = realm
                .where(RealmUser.class)
                .in("id", ids)
                .findAllAsync();

        realmResults.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<RealmUser>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(@NonNull RealmResults<RealmUser> realmUsers) {

                if (realmUsers.size() > 0) {

                    List<RealmUser> users = realm.copyFromRealm(realmUsers);

                    callback.onSuccess(users);

                    realmResults.removeAllChangeListeners();

                }
            }
        });
```

If i wrap it inside `try/finally` block the code doesn't work, if i close the realm inside `onChange`,  `onChange` may never be called.

note: i am using synced realm with realm platform.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do. Not only do you not preserve the RealmResults reference which means it can be consumed by GC, you also map out all the items on the UI thread. I don't get it?

Comment: i am trying to encapsulate realm in repository class, call repository>get data>close realm

Comment: In that case you'd have to do the exact same thing as what I did in https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-monarchy/ (specifically in [**here**](https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-monarchy/blob/67209635e58369b01d4d63b59bd95f917227dac7/monarchy/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/monarchy/Monarchy.java)). But beware that I couldn't get Paging positional data source integration to work with async queries (which are required to create subscriptions against sync realm). But regular `findAllAsync()` would work.

Comment: Okay thanks, but basically i see that the RealmResults\PermmisionManagers\Realms need to be tight to the view lifecycle , in your case it attached to livedata that and closes resources when it is onInactive() called

Comment: You can create LiveData in onCreate, observeForever in onCreate, and removeObserver in onDestroy.